# Why did the assigning of an unrelated string cause another string to be modified?

Tags: c++

Example below, I have fn as a const pointer pointing to a constant c-string. When I declare and assign an unrelated other const pointer to a different constant c-string, the original fn gets modified. I have been trying to figure out why for a while, but can't see what can possibly cause this?

Output:

Original fn: sampleStrWithExtension

Modified fn: randomStr2ModifiedFn

```
int main() {
        std::string baseString = "sampleStr";
        std::string randomBaseString = "randomStr2";
        const char* const fn = (baseString + "WithExtension").c_str();
        std::cout << "Original fn: " << fn << std::endl;
        const char* const variableNotFn = (randomBaseString + "ModifiedFn").c_str();
        std::cout << "Modified fn: " << fn << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `fn = (baseString + "WithExtension").c_str()` is not a very afe assignment. The `string` object created by the expression `baseString + "WithExtension"` is destroyed immediate after this assignment is completed, leaving the variable `fn` pointing to unallocated memory, which could reused at any time.

Comment: The lifetime of `x.c_str()` never extends past the lifetime of `x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const char* const fn = (baseString + "WithExtension").c_str();
```

This results in undefined behavior.

```
baseString + "WithExtension"
```

This creates a temporary `std::string` object. The `+` operator on a `std::string` returns a new `std::string`, and in the context of this expression, the returned `std::string` becomes a temporary object. `c_str()` returns a pointer to this temporary object's internal buffer.

The pointer returned by `c_str()` is valid only until its `std::string` is modified, or it gets destroyed. At the end of the above expression, the temporary object gets destroyed.

The use of this pointer later results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not an undefined behavior. It's just a pointer to a not any more existing string. The undefined behavior happens when you dereference it